# requiring lib/modules/file.rb in my app/services/service.rb file. How do I do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module in my lib/modules/module.rb folder and a service object in my app/services/service.rb file. I am trying to have access to the methods that I defined in module.rb in my service object in my app/services/service.rb file. I want to be able to call module methods in service.rb.

I have this line written:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

in my application.rb file. What am I doing wrong? What else do I need to do?

In case you need it, my service.rb file looks like this and is a PORO.

```
class FindTrip

  attr_reader :destination,
              :origin,
              :departure_date,
              :return_date,
              :max_price,
              :qpx_service

...

end
```

Comment: Show us please, how are you requiring the file. From this point `require 'modules/file'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1) Specify path to `lib/modules` directory in autoloads paths:

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)
```

or

2) Specify `Modules` namespace in your module class. i.e for `lib/modules/my_module.rb` it should be:

```
    module Modules
      module MyModule
        ...
      end
    end
```

and use full path to module: `Modules::MyModule`.

Comment: Can you clarify point number 2? Again, I have a lib/modules.module.rb file and a service object in my app/services/service.rb. How can I call my methods in my module in my service.rb file?

Comment: In second case you should leave your autoloading code: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and call `MyModule` from your service as: `Modules::MyModule.module_method` for example.